# не распознает модуль discord

Tags: python, discord.py, модули

Решил я создать своего бота. Начал разбираться. Сначала все отлично получалось(для меня). Создал второго, третьего. На четвертом стало выдавать ошибку. Сам модуль использовал, но pycharm его не распознает. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Опишите проблему конкретнее. Вы создали 4 ботов, но pycharm не распознает модуль `discord`? Как вы тогда создали 3 предыдущих ботов? Если pycharm перестал распознавать библиотеку только на 4 боте, то так и напишите. Прикрепите сообщение об ошибке, которую выдает pycharm, иначе, как по вашему вам смогут помочь? Если до этого 3 бота работали корректно, посмотрите внимательно, чем отличается структура проекта у 4 бота от 3 предыдущих. Может быть вы создали 4 бота на ПК, где нет библиотеки `discord`? **При подобных странных проблемах вот это все должно быть расписано в тексте вопроса.**